# Unable to import excel to DB table in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using the below code to import excel data into DB table. The code works fine in my local and when I move this code to server the import fails in between. Also I don't get any error messages and I get a message data saved successfully.

For Ex: The excel has 75,000 data's and only 13,500 records are getting inserted and the size of the excel file is 5 MB.

Any suggestions about the possible problems?

**CS:**

```
protected void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strCS = string.Empty; ;
            string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadExcel.FileName).ToLower();
            string query = "";
            lblError.Text = "";
            string FileName = string.Empty;
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
            string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];   
            string path = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(FileUploadExcel.FileName));
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(FolderPath) + path);       
            FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FolderPath) + path);   
            string filePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath) + path;

            if (strFileType != String.Empty)
            {
                if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
                {
                    strCS = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
                {
                    strCS = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please upload the correct file format')", true);
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCS);
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        conn.Open();
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string sheetname = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                    query = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetname + "]";
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn = null;
                    }
                    string strSqlTable = "TABLENAME";
                    string sclearsql = "delete from " + strSqlTable;
                    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlconn.Close();
                    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(strCS);
                    oledbconn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbconn);
                    oledbcmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
                    OleDbDataReader dReader = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strCon);
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = strSqlTable;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 120;
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dReader);
                    oledbconn.Close();
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data saved successfully');window.location='Panel.aspx';", true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded due to following reasons.Please check: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a file to import the data.')", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded due to following reasons.Please check: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi remove the data reader on you code which read the excel file twice and use the dataset to fill out your SQL table:

See below:

```
DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCS))
            {
                conn.Open();

                DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

                //Looping a first Sheet of Xl File
                DataRow schemaRow = schemaTable.Rows[0];
                string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
                {
                    string query = "SELECT  * FROM [" + sheet + "]";
                    OleDbDataAdapter daexcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    dtexcel.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    daexcel.Fill(dtexcel);
                }
            }

            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconn))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = strSqlTable;

                    sqlconn.Open();

                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtexcel);

                }
            }
```

Comment: I actually used this code initially and this didn't work too. I'm wondering when it works in local why this doesn't work in the server. Any compatability issue?

Comment: Please see my updated code. Can you post a dummy sql connection you are using to connect with your server? I used that code to import 350k records and I don't have any issue.

Comment: `public static string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`  IN WEB.CONFIG FILE `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=SQL\SQL;Database=DBWind;User ID=AX;Password=XX;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>`

Comment: I don't see any problem in  the connection string. The Sqlbulk copy takes a while depends on the Server that you are connected with. So lets say it takes a minute in Local then 5 minutes in server. Maybe you also need to check the length and the data types of the columns of the excel file and  the SQL table you are inserting the data if its match.

Comment: I have checked the datatypes length and it all seems perfect.

Comment: Try to upload first the excel using SSIS or Import Data in SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the dts wizard? it is a nice tool if you have a excel sheet with data.
you use it by opening the command prompt. **windowsbutton + r, and the write cmd**.
and from in here you write **dtswizard**
then a wizard opens in a new window where you can select the excel sheet that you want to insert. There is many tutorials on google. 
Hope you can use this

Comment: The problem is this need to be done in .net UI or else I could have done this in SSIS with ease.